# How to view the web server http response size in KB?

Tags: asp.net, html, firefox, google-chrome, scalability

I include jquery, jquery-UI and some jquery plugins in my website and I'd like to know the size in kb of each response, specially the first one. How can I see it in Firefox, Chrome and IE8?

Thank you.

Comment: it's `KB` (or `KiB`) but neither `kB`, `Kb` nor `kb`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Google Chrome

Open Chrome Developer tools by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and select **Network**.
*Size* column is the one you're interested in.

### Firefox

Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and open it by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and select **Net** tab.
*Size* column is the one you're interested in.

### Internet Explorer

> *Why would you want to see server response sizes in IE when you already got that information from the other two browsers?* **;-)**

No direct support in IE8 (or older for that matter). Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) local proxy tool when you can't use other browser.

#### Fiddler

It is actually a very powerful tool (browser independent) so you can use it with any requests going from your machine to some web server. These requests may be initiated by a browser (any) or your desktop application that makes requests to some web server. That's why this tools is invaluable to any developer since it provides many many features. You can even make requests directly from it.

Comment: Also at the bottom you can see the total requests and KB transfered

Comment: @Robert by the moment I can only develop with IE8 this is because I need to know the size in IE8. Later I migrate to FF o CH :)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Until now I used IE dev. tools and they were enough for my need.

Comment: ...you forgot to mention that IE8 DevTools also gave you a lot of coffee time, since everything becomes extremely slow when you enable script debugging: *Let's have a coffee while page loads* kinda thing. ;-)